# Nested SplitList Problem for quick expansion

Tags: macros, pdftex, latex3, xparse, splitargument

I'm thinking whether I can write a new command for quick inserting any number of small groups of vectors in vector space. Here is what I want:

```latex
$\basis{x; u; v}$
```

will automatically resolve to:

```latex
$x_1, \sim x_n ; u_1, \sim u_n ; v_1, \sim v_n$
```

But if I want to change any beginning and ending subscripts, I want to have the command with such syntax:

```latex
$\basis{ {x,2,k}; {u, 3, n-1}; {v, 1, r} }$
```

to be resolved to:

```latex
$x_{2}, \sim x_{k} ; u_3, \sim u_{n-1} ; v_1, \sim v_{r}$
```

or even more flexible like:

```latex
$\basis{x; {u, 2, k }; v}$
```

and the scripts for `x` and `v` remain default values (1 to n).

What I currently have is:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\basisPrivate}{ m O{1} O{n} } {
    {#1}_{#2} \sim {#1}_{#3}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\basis} { >{\SplitList{;}}m } {
    { \ProcessList{#1}{\basisPrivate} }
}
```

This can only works for the most simple case:

```latex
$\basis{m; n; k}$
```

But I don't know how to achieve the second one.

May someone show me some suggestions on whether this is do-able or how to do this? Any help would be appreciated!

**Update:**

Thank you @wipet, @egreg, @Mico for your invaluable solutions and putting time for answering my question.

I didn't expect to get so powerful and general templates here!

@wipet's solution has the philosophy of simplicity;

@egreg kind of provides a complete small library tailored for my need!

@Mico's template is also very general. But since I'm not very familiar with `lua`'s syntax, thus I got to test it later.

I'd rather not just mark any one as the "best" solution here, what you guys presented here is pure gold. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

What we can do using TeX primitives directly:

```
\def\basis #1{\basisA#1;}
\def\basisA #1;#2;#3;{\basisB#1;;\basisB#2;;\basisB#3;}
\def\basisB #1#2;{\iscomma#1#2,\iffalse \basisC#1#2,1,n;\else \basisC#1#2;\fi}
\def\basisC #1,#2,#3;{#1_{#2}, \sim #1_{#3}}
\def\iscomma #1,#2\iffalse{\ifx"#2"}

%% tests:

$\basis{x; u; v}$

$\basis{ {x,2,k}; {u, 3, n-1}; {v, 1, r} }$

$\basis{x; {u, 2, k }; v}$

\bye
```

Comment: Thank you @wipet! Glad that I learned how to solve it with just TeX primitives!

Answer (score 4):

Complex tasks require lower (and more powerful) level facilities.

The idea is to

1. have global default end and start indices;
2. split the input at semicolons and treat each item separately;
3. if an item has no commas, use the default;
4. if an item has one comma, use the second part as the end index;
5. if an item has two commas, use the second and third part for start and end indices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\basis}{O{n}mO{1}}
 {% #1 = default end index
  % #2 = items
  % #3 = default start index
  \zhuoqun_basis:nnn { #2 } { #3 } { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__zhuoqun_basis_groups_seq
\seq_new:N \l__zhuoqun_basis_group_seq
\tl_new:N \l__zhuoqun_basis_groups_first_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \zhuoqun_basis:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__zhuoqun_basis_groups_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__zhuoqun_basis_groups_seq \l__zhuoqun_basis_groups_first_seq
  \__zhuoqun_basis_item:Vnn \l__zhuoqun_basis_groups_first_seq { #2 } { #3 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__zhuoqun_basis_groups_seq
   {
    ;\mspace{\thickmuskip}
    \__zhuoqun_basis_item:nnn { ##1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__zhuoqun_basis_item:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__zhuoqun_basis_group_seq { , } { #1 }
  \int_case:nn { \seq_count:N \l__zhuoqun_basis_group_seq }
   {
    {1}{\__zhuoqun_basis_make:eee
        { \seq_item:Nn \l__zhuoqun_basis_group_seq { 1 } }
        { #2 }
        { #3 }
       }
    {2}{\__zhuoqun_basis_make:eee
        { \seq_item:Nn \l__zhuoqun_basis_group_seq { 1 } }
        { #2 }
        { \seq_item:Nn \l__zhuoqun_basis_group_seq { 2 } }
       }
    {3}{\__zhuoqun_basis_make:eee
        { \seq_item:Nn \l__zhuoqun_basis_group_seq { 1 } }
        { \seq_item:Nn \l__zhuoqun_basis_group_seq { 2 } }
        { \seq_item:Nn \l__zhuoqun_basis_group_seq { 3 } }
       }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__zhuoqun_basis_item:nnn { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__zhuoqun_basis_make:nnn
 {
  #1\sb{#2},\dots,#1\sb{#3}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__zhuoqun_basis_make:nnn { eee }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\basis{x} \\
\basis{x}[2] \\
\basis[m]{x}[2] \\
\basis{x; u; v} \\
\basis{x; u; v}[2] \\
\basis[m]{x; u; v}[2] \\
\basis{x,2,k; u, 3, n-1; v,r}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\dots` that's more customary than `\sim`.

Comment: Thank you @egreg! It is so helpful! You basically implemented what I have thought in mind and much more

Answer (score 2):

For good measure, a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

Observe that the inputs can be quite general.

- They needn't be single-character entities; instead, they can be something like `t_0`, `\kappa`, and `\beta^*`.
- The inputs needn't be ascii-encoded; indeed, they may be general utf8-encoded glyphs. (If a utf8-encoded glyph occurs in a text font but not in the prevailing math font, it'll be necessary to encase it in an `\mbox` wrapper.)
- If you would rather have `,\sim` than `,\dots,` as the connector, just change the line

  ```
  tex.sprint (j1.."_{"..j2.."},\\dots,"..j1.."_{"..j3.."}")
  ```

  to

  ```
  tex.sprint (j1.."_{"..j2.."},\\sim"..j1.."_{"..j3.."}")
  ```

---

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' env. and '\luastringN' macro
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function basis ( s )
  -- split the input string into constituent components
  args = {}
  for zz in unicode.utf8.gmatch ( s , "[^%;]+" ) do
     table.insert ( args , zz )
  end    
  -- process each component in turn
  for i=1,#args do
    ii = args[i] -- select i'th row of the table
    _, c = unicode.utf8.gsub ( ii , "%," , "" ) -- count instances of ','
    if c==0 then 
      j1=ii; j2="1"; j3="n"
    else 
      iii={} -- initialize a scratch table
      for zz in unicode.utf8.gmatch ( ii , "[^%,]+" ) do 
        table.insert ( iii , zz )
      end 
      j1=iii[1];
      if c==1 then 
        j2 = "1"; j3 = iii[2]
      else
        j2 = iii[2]; j3 = iii[3]
      end
    end 
    -- print the result
    tex.sprint (j1.."_{"..j2.."},\\dots,"..j1.."_{"..j3.."}")
    if i<#args then 
      tex.sprint ( ";" ) -- separator between tuples
    end
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% LaTeX-side code: Define a utility macro.
%% Note: We take care not to expand its argument.
\newcommand\basis[1]{\directlua{basis(\luastringN{#1})}}

\begin{document}
$\basis{y ; z, t_0, t_n; \beta^*,\kappa}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mico! Definitely gonna try `lua` when I got free time. The syntax looks really neat.

Answer (score 1):

For the fun, a solution with the LPEG of LuaLaTeX.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
local function one_element(x,i,j)
  i , j = j and i or j or "1" , j or i or "n"
  return x .. "_{" .. i .. "} , \\dots , " .. x .. "_{" .. j .. "}" 
end 

lpeg.locale(lpeg)
local P , S , C , V = lpeg.P , lpeg.S , lpeg.C, lpeg.V

local MyLPEG = 
  P { "E" , 
      E = V "F" * ( C ( P ";" ) * V "F" ) ^ 0 , 
      F = ( V "G" * ( P "," * V "G" ) ^ -2 ) / one_element ,
      G = C ( ( 1 - S ",;" ) ^ 0 ) }

function basis(s) return tex.sprint(MyLPEG : match(s)) end 
\end{luacode}

\NewDocumentCommand{\basis}{m}{\directlua{basis(\luastringN{#1})}}

\begin{document}
$\basis{y ; z, t_0, t_n; \beta^*, \kappa }$
\end{document}
```

The behavior is the same as the behavior of Mico's answer.

Comment: Thank you @F.Pantigny!